# How can I make my concrete countertop smoother?

Tags: concrete, sanding, countertops, polish

I think I used the wrong concrete mix. It had rocks in it so when I tried to get it level, but I really struggled.

I then went and bought some self leveling cement to try to balance everything out. It looks better but it is not flawless.

I whitewashed it to give it a white look because the white pigment didn't take.

My next step was to seal it with Valspar Wet seal.

My questions are:

1. Will the sealant fill in the grooves to give a smooth leveled feel?  Or Would Epoxy be better for the job?
2. Looking at the pictures, what would you do to give this a professional touch, or make it as clean as possible?

ALT. option

Should I build up the edges with  melamine board so that it becomes 2 - 2.5 inches, then pour more concrete on top?

I greatly appreciate your advice and feedback. Im trying to make this look right. My wife is nervous it wont look good, but Im confident it can turn out [right. Just need a little help.

[Photo 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_9wxULV54xXU3BuNjhMeV80T3c) | [Photo 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_9wxULV54xXQUxIaFBvazY4dEU)

Comment: Are you going about this the correct way? I thought that concrete counter tops were made in a mold and then flipped over and placed over the cabinets. Often made in sections.

Comment: I was using the pour in place method

Comment: OK.....your issue does expose that this method does have its significant drawbacks. Reverse moulding with carefully build forms can lead to the perfect flat surface that you are after with a whole lot less post surface finishing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just using sealant, it sounds like the best approach is sanding/polishing.

Pour-in-place produces rough concrete, as you have discovered.

Begin with very coarse sandpaper then as it gets more smooth you can use ever-finer grit until you achieve the surface you intended.

Comment: thanks you.  The secondary problem is, it is not level.

Comment: Sanding is the only way to do it correctly adding thin layers on top will be prone to cracking. There are lots of DIY videos on how to finish. This takes time but will last years and look awesome if done correctly. For white I use white Portland cement not the standard gray. You may want to dye the surface after grinding then seal.

Comment: Maybe you can level it as you sand it.